# Have iFrame fill screen minus a set pixel footer

Tags: html, css, iframe

How do you get an **iframe to fill up the height of the screen minus a 33px footer space at the bottom**?  I need the scrollbars of the iframe (both up and down arrow) to show.  And it must be without Javascript (so it can degrade pleasantly :).

*(The only thing I've found on SO is to use `padding-top` which doesn't seem to work in my case):*

```
<body>
  <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; bottom: 33px;">
      <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="http://google.com" 
       style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top: 33px;">
      </iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 33px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; background: red;">
       /* Footer Content */
  </div>
</body>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Perhaps I'm just tired, but it seems like padding-top would have the opposite desired effect. Wouldn't you want padding-bottom:33px and then position the footer in that blank space?

Comment: @Moses - `padding-bottom` takes care of clearing out a blank space, true.  But combined with `height:100%` it pushes the scroll bars of the iframe off the top of the window.

Comment: Why are you using an iframe if you want it to behave almost exactly like regular frames?

Comment: Because I need some of the behavior of iframes.  That div at the bottom has popout menus that i want to partially overlap the iframe content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with [GASPS] `<table>` but for the life of me, I can't get it work with `<div>`. You are right, it is pushing the `<iframe>` scrollbars around. In any case, here's something for you to work with until you get it working with `<div>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
table{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:none;
}
td{
    padding:0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="http://google.com" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll; margin:0px; padding:0px;"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td style='height:33px;'>
                <div style="height: 33px; width:100%; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; background: red;">
                   /* Footer Content */
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice: Don't use strict doctype. `<iframe>` is not supported.

PS. the `html,body{}` is key.

Comment: Tested in Chrome. Didn't get to test in anything else, it's 2:30 here and I just spent too long trying to solve it. Ha! Let me know if it works or not!

Comment: @Jason, `table` is just as good as `div` in my book (i'd still name my first born after you), but alas it's not working.  Not in Chrome, FF, IE.  Basically the first row is only about 200px high (i.e., **the iFrame isn't the height of the screen minus 33px**).

Comment: @Jason, one more thing: I copied and pasted your code, but if you're getting the right behavior, maybe the mistake is mine.  Doctype?  Something else?  Let me know.  Looks like a lot of thought in this and I thank you.

Comment: What is your doctype? I'll look into, because it looked beautiful on Chrome.

Comment: I have updated to fix it. This must work! haha, let me know! I was not specifying a doctype in the original.

Comment: +1, check: @Jason, totally looks beautiful in Chrome.  It's not working in IE or FF.  Still, assuming a world of Chrome users, this does the trick!  Thanks for all the thought and work!

Comment: Man, I checked it in FF and I remember it looking good. Nonetheless, hope you can get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;>
  <div style="position:relative; top:0; right:0; bottom:33px; left:0;">
      <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; bottom: 33px; position:fixed">
          <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" src="http://google.com" 
           style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll">
          </iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 33px; width:100%; bottom: 0px; position: absolute; background: red;">
       /* Footer Content */
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what browser?  I've tested it in IE, FF, Chrome, and Safari just to make sure.  The top scroll arrow doesn't show up in a `height: 100%` case because the position ends up being `-33px top`

Comment: @Emile My mistake. I updated it again, I've only tested it in chrome though.

Comment: @Emile as for the scroll bar I'm not too sure.

Comment: sorry but the scroll bar is the key to the question :)